# Flutter: how to differentiate between long press and long press AND drag

Tags: flutter

How to differentiate between long press VS long press combined with dragging (first long press, then drag without lifting the finger in between)? I'm specifically curious how to do that with a gesture detector?

Answer (score 0):

where you click on one, you pull your hand out in a different position on the other.

```
double? xStart;
      double? yStart;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onLongPressStart: (details) {
            xStart = details.globalPosition.dx;
            yStart = details.globalPosition.dy;
          },
          onLongPressEnd: (details) {
            double xCurrent = details.globalPosition.dx;
            double yCurrent = details.globalPosition.dy;
            double threshold = 10.0;
    
            if ((xStart! - xCurrent).abs() < threshold &&
                (yStart! - yCurrent).abs() < threshold) {
              print('Long press detected');
            } else {
              print('Drag detected');
            }
          },
          child:
              Center(child: Container(color: Colors.blue, width: 300, height: 300)),
        );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).